# Methods to deal with latent variables

Tags: regression, latent-variable, treatment-effect, observational-study, mixed-model

I had a general question about methods to adjust for the effect of latent variables (specially variables that are suspected to be confounder) in observational studies. In particular, I'm working on a project where I'm interested to evaluate the effect of a supplementary math software on students math scores.Consider a block randomized trial where each grade in a school (with all classes in that grade) is randomly assigned to be either CTRL or TRT. We know that "Teacher Effect" is a dominant effect in students math scores with an effect size of 2 to 3 times of the software that I'm trying to evaluate its effect. Teachers in fact have confounding effect as they might be related to how the software being used and also it is related to math scores (outcome). In this situation, failure to adjust for teacher effect may lead to highly biased results. The problem is there is absolutely no way to quantitatively measure "Teacher Effect". How can I run analyses that take this latent effect into account to avoid bias?

Really appreciate your thoughts and ideas in advance.

Comment: Theoretically, since you are randomly allocating the participants to control or treatment, the known and unknown confounding variables should be equally distributed. So the "teacher effect" should be controlled for due to the randomization.